# Docker service discovery does not work with default bridge

Tags: docker, docker-network

Seems like docker service discovery just works with user defined networks and not with default bridge *(docker0)*, but I didn't find anything in the docs.

`docker run --rm -d --name c1 alpine sleep 2h`
`docker run --rm -d --name c2 alpine sleep 2h`
`docker exec -ti c1 ping c2`

It gives me `ping: bad address 'c2'`

But if I create a custom bridge network everthing works fine:
`docker network create u-bridge`
`docker run --rm -d --name u1 --net u-bridge alpine sleep 2h`
`docker run --rm -d --name u2 --net u-bridge alpine sleep 2h`
`docker exec -ti u1 ping u2`

It gives me: `PING u2 (172.18.0.3): 56 data bytes (...)`

Shouldn't default bridge network have service discovery?

Answer (score 6):

Containers on the default bridge need to be explicitly [linked](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/), which is considered legacy/deprecated behaviour.

> Warning: The `--link` flag is a deprecated legacy feature of Docker. It may 
>   eventually be removed. Unless you absolutely need to continue using
>   it, we recommend that you use user-defined networks to facilitate
>   communication between two containers instead of using `--link`. One
>   feature that user-defined networks do not support that you can do with
>   `--link` is sharing environmental variables between containers. However, you can use other mechanisms such as volumes to share environment
>   variables between containers in a more controlled way.

User defined networks should be used instead, as you have demonstrated.

Answer (score 2):

DNS lookup for default bridge and user-defined network works differently.

Refer to this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/