# Docker: Client not connecting to Eureka Server

Tags: java, spring, maven, docker, netflix-eureka

I want to create a container for my client and a container for my server and connect them.

Client:

```
server.port=8084
spring.application.name=articlemicroservice

#already tried localhost & hostIp 
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://discovery:8761/eureka

eureka.client.fetchRegristry=true
eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:shop
```

Server:

```
server.port=8761
spring.application.name=eureka-server

eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
# eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds: 2
```

I created both containers with the docker-maven-plugin. The dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM java
ADD /articlemicroservice.jar //
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/articlemicroservice.jar"]
```

To start a container I use

```
docker run -it -p 8761:8761 eurekaserver
docker run -it -p 8084:8084 articlemicroservice
```

When I start the Cient I just get: "com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server" and

```
 "2019-03-15 17:54:51.439  WARN 1 --- [nfoReplicator-0] c.n.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator     : There was a problem with the instance info replicator"
```

Did I forget something in the properties?

**Edit:** This is the configuration of the docker-maven-plugin:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <imageName>articlemicroservice</imageName>
            <baseImage>java</baseImage>
            <entryPoint>["java", "-jar", "/${project.build.finalName}.jar"]</entryPoint>
            <!-- copy the service's jar file from target into the root directory 
                of the image -->
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                    <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                    <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated, running containers individually will get connected to docker bridge default network with container name.

Since you haven't mentioned the container name and it doesn't resolve the service by name mentioned in the property file

```
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://discovery:8761/eureka
```

To make it work by running containers directly, use container ip of the eureka-server

```
# start eureka server container
$ docker run  --name eureka-server -p 8081:8081 -d -rm eureka-server

# start eureka client container
$ docker run --name eureka-client -p 8082:8082 -d --rm -e EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE=http://172.17.0.2:8081/eureka eureka-client
```

Inspect default bridge network to find the containers attached and its ips

```
$ docker network inspect bridge


 "Containers": {
            "4e4ce0e24091bda8e78805faad7ee31ba12fe5cd266c9d8a51dacf5b88813a67": {
                "Name": "eureka-client",
                "EndpointID": "edb2d9b333e6b974cfcf939e1585847c82c7ddebde5c44065f1e101ff12cb2bd",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c4534a928c71430414b95324a3626aa5c0bf6535a5ffce1fe38a060cfc07d0df": {
                "Name": "eureka-server",
                "EndpointID": "af82ea5ca05283bac6634ee877e8e3c40c7cdbe7d3c2126bfb53c9db1747d0cc",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
```

Perfect solution is to use docker compose.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  eureka-server:
    image: eureka-server
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  eureka-client:
    build: eureka-client
    ports:
      - "8082:8082"
    environment:
      EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE: http://eureka-server:8080/eureka
```

Read more here :

[Link containers in default docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46781444/docker-service-discovery-does-not-work-with-default-bridge)

Comment: Docker newbie here. What is the meaning of "eureka-server" on the last line in docker-compose.yml above? Is that like a reference to the eureka-server: service definition above? will it resolve to the service IP address? I have tried to find the answer to that in dockerfile reference to no avail.

Comment: How to read ```EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICEURL_DEFAULTZONE``` in spring application?